# Creating the number of shortest paths in a directed Graph

Tags: c, directed-graph, breadth-first-search

my homework is Creating the number of shortest paths from S to any other vertex in a directed Graph using c language

the graph is shown as a txt file like this:

```
3 // number of vertex in G
{2,3},{1},{} // in the first {} we can see the neighbors for V1 , in the second for V2 and so on
```

and i have to print an array of number of shortest path for s

the algorithm i use is like BFS with some adds:
numOfShortest(G,S)

```
for vertex x which belongs to gropu V-S 
do color[x]=white, d[x]=0, F[x]=0
color[s]=gray,d[s]=0,F[s]=1
while Q is not empty //= let Q be a queue
 do u=dequeue(Q)
  for each vertex v = N(u) // = for every neighbor of u
   do if color[v] = white 
    then color[v]= gray, d[v]=d[u]+1 
       F[v]=f[v]+f[u] // = v must have atleast the same number of paths as u
       enqueue(Q,v)
      else if color[v]=gray 
       then if d[u] < d[v]
        then f[v]=f[v]+f[u]
  color[u]=black // = when finished with every N(u)
```

now i have to take a few things into account ( correct me if im wrong)

- implement a enqueue using a linked list
- make a struct called vertex for each v which contains the neightbors
  ( using a dynamic array )
- i need somehow to scan the neighbors written on the file to the
  neighbors on the struct vertex

perhaps i took it too far with the preparations and there is a more simple way to do that, i got some mess in my mind. 
thanks to whoever can help

Answer (score 1):

You should start having a look at the Dijkstra algorithm to get the shortest path from one vertex S to every other vertex in the graph.

Then maybe mixing it with a BFS-like algorithm will help you counting what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 2D array to store the entire graph.

Let `int a[][]` the 2D array.

As this is your assignment I am not going to give you the code but can give a way- how to store the graph.

First assign to each g[i][j]=0; This means j is not neighbor of i.

Then take the number of node in a variable and use a loop for taking neighbors in a sequence. And save the neighbors in the array i.e. for your input file.

```
NumOfNode = 3

a[1][2] = 1;  
a[1][3] = 1;

a[2][1] = 1;
```

After that you in your algorithm if you get `a[i][j]` is 1 then there is a path from i to j. If `a[i][j]` is 0 then there is no path from i to j.

This [link](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Graph_data_structures) may help you.

Comment: thanks, but i forgot the mention the code complexity needs to be O(V+E)

Comment: @ItayZaguri You can use any algorithms that suits your complexity on the graph `a[][]`. I just showed you how you can store the graph from file to an array. If you want implementation of algorithm then google it. There are plenty of codes.